# Drawing of a "thick" subset of the unity sphere

Tags: tikz-pgf

Let A be a subset of the unity sphere as in the next picture:
[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\shade[ball color=blue, opacity=0.4] (0,0) circle (2);
\draw (0,0) circle (2);
\fill[fill=blue!80,rotate around={60:(1,1)}] (1,1) ellipse (0.3 and 0.5);
\draw[rotate around={60:(1,1)}] (1,1) ellipse (0.3 and 0.5);
\node at (1,1) {$A$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I want to draw the set `$\{tx | x\in A,\: t\in (1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon)\}$` for a small epsilon. This set is like the "transform" of A from a thin region to a "slightly thicker" one.

It may be a nice idea to draw a "cone" from the origin to A ans surpassing it so the viewer can understand what we are doing.

How could we do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 3d coordinates you can use `tikz-3dplot` to achieve the appropriate orthographic projections.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=-30]
 \draw[ball color=blue,fill opacity=0.4] (0,0) coordinate(O) circle (2);
 \tdplotsetmaincoords{50}{00}
 \begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords]
  \draw[fill=red,fill opacity=0.2] (O) --
  plot[smooth,variable=\x,
  domain={\tdplotmainphi-90/cot(\tdplotmaintheta)}:{\tdplotmainphi+90/cot(\tdplotmaintheta)}] 
   (xyz spherical cs:radius=2.5,latitude=70,longitude=\x) -- cycle;
  \draw[fill=blue] plot[smooth,variable=\x,domain=0:360] 
   (xyz spherical cs:radius=2,latitude=70,longitude=\x);
  \node at (0,0,2) {A}; 
  \draw[fill=red,fill opacity=0.2] (O) --
  plot[smooth,variable=\x,
  domain={\tdplotmainphi+90/cot(\tdplotmaintheta)}:{\tdplotmainphi+360-90/cot(\tdplotmaintheta)}] 
   (xyz spherical cs:radius=2.5,latitude=70,longitude=\x) -- cycle;
  \draw[fill=red,fill opacity=0.2] plot[smooth,variable=\x,domain=0:360] 
   (xyz spherical cs:radius=2.5,latitude=70,longitude=\x);
 \end{scope}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This makes the blue area "thick".

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=-30]
 \draw[ball color=blue,fill opacity=0.4] (0,0) coordinate(O) circle (2);
 \tdplotsetmaincoords{50}{00}
 \begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords]
  \draw[dashed] (O) --
  plot[smooth,variable=\x,
  domain={\tdplotmainphi-90/cot(\tdplotmaintheta)}:{\tdplotmainphi+90/cot(\tdplotmaintheta)}] 
   (xyz spherical cs:radius=2.5,latitude=70,longitude=\x) -- cycle;
  \draw[fill=blue] plot[smooth,variable=\x,domain=0:360] 
   (xyz spherical cs:radius=2.1,latitude=70,longitude=\x);
  \draw[fill=blue!70] 
   plot[smooth,variable=\x,domain={\tdplotmainphi+90/cot(\tdplotmaintheta)}:{\tdplotmainphi+360-90/cot(\tdplotmaintheta)}] 
   (xyz spherical cs:radius=2,latitude=70,longitude=\x)
    -- 
    plot[smooth,variable=\x,domain={\tdplotmainphi+360-90/cot(\tdplotmaintheta)}:{\tdplotmainphi+90/cot(\tdplotmaintheta)}] 
    (xyz spherical cs:radius=2.1,latitude=70,longitude=\x) ;
  \node at (0,0,2) {A}; 
  \draw[dashed] (O) --
  plot[smooth,variable=\x,
  domain={\tdplotmainphi+90/cot(\tdplotmaintheta)}:{\tdplotmainphi+360-90/cot(\tdplotmaintheta)}] 
   (xyz spherical cs:radius=2.5,latitude=70,longitude=\x) -- cycle;
 \end{scope}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @marmot, what I had in mind was very close to what you did but the set I described is like a "thickened" A. How could I do it? The cone is nice but it is not the most important part of the picture, which is the "thickened" A, so maybe we could do it in dashed (or dotted) lines?

Comment: @Gabriel I added something.